# CircularRevealAnimation and TapTargetAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I achieve CircularRevealAnimation while opening new activity on Fab click event.! Also how to get this view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB871.png)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
public void startCircularReveal() {
    final View view = findViewById(R.id.revealView);
    final View startView = findViewById(R.id.button_container);
    int cx = (startView.getLeft() + startView.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (startView.getTop() + startView.getBottom()) / 2;
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6FA6FF"));
    int finalRadius = Math.max(cy , view.getHeight() - cy);
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(200);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();
}
```

Change the view startView to your FAB view, and onAnimationEnd do whatever you want after the reveal is finished.

Now add this to the bottom of your xml

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/revealView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/custom_theme_color"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:visibility="invisible">
</FrameLayout>
```

This view is where the reveal will be on top of ( named view at the start startCircularReveal() method ), hope it helps.

Comment: This seems to be working for existing view, but how can I pass newActivity while opening it on fab click.

Comment: @Deepesh just call startActivity(new Intent(this,activity.class)); inside onAnimationEnd()

Comment: I am starting activity from fragment, will it also work in this case?

Comment: @Deepesh Yeah same thing just replace this by getActivity()

Comment: @Deepesh call it like this :  getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),OtherActivity.class))

Comment: Its showing the animation but what is happening is like First, Its showing CircularRevealAnimation on the xml view (revealview),  then opening my new activity independently with its default transition which doesnt seems like properly integrated and lastly when i am hitting back then it shows revealview instead of source activity which I think will be resolved after making reveal view invisible, but dont know what to do to fix first two problems

Comment: Well you didn't anything mention about the animation of the other activity, anyway you can call getActivity().finish();
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout); just after startActivity, and about back button reanimation you can override exit transition of the reveal, you can look in the internet there is plenty of resources.

Comment: I still do not get the desired output but it seems I am very close to it now Thanks for your efforts .